# How to store multiple selected row items in mutable array in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, uitableview

I had written code for displaying the tableview with 3 sections and now i want to store the selected row item into an array and when ever i tried this below code i am getting array value is nil. suggest me how to solve this problem 
 Below i am adding code and Json sample data

```html
{
  "technicians": {
    "group": [
      {
        "first_name": "First",
        "last_name": "Available",
        "id": ""
      },
      {
        "first_name": "idea",
        "last_name": "Chandra",
        "id": 2885
      },
      {
        "first_name": "manson",
        "last_name": "Tolios",
        "id": 2878
      },
      {
        "first_name": "tata",
        "last_name": "Masson",
        "id": 2869
      }
    ],
    "client": [
      {
        "first_name": "tsms",
        "last_name": "ysys",
        "id": 2875
      },
      {
        "first_name": "Oscar",
        "last_name": "tata",
        "id": 2851
      },
      {
        "first_name": "Peter",
        "last_name": "yaha",
        "id": 2873
      },
      {
        "first_name": "iaka",
        "last_name": "adad",
        "id": 2847
      },
      {
        "first_name": "taga",
        "last_name": "uaja",
        "id": 2917
      }
    ],
    "contractors": [
      {
        "first_name": "taha"
      },
      {
        "first_name": "haka"
      },
      {
        "first_name": "oala"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```html
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EcsStafflist"];
        if(!cell)
        {
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
    
        }
        UILabel *Fname = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:18];
    
        UILabel *Lname = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:19];
    
        Fname.text = [[[mydic objectForKey:[MysectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"first_name"];
    
        Lname.text = [[[mydic objectForKey:[MysectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"last_name"];
    
        if (indexPath.row %2 ==1)
    
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.60 green:0.60 blue:0.95 alpha:1.0];
    
        else
    
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.64 green:0.89 blue:0.61 alpha:1.0];

        return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  stringId = [[[mydic objectForKey:[MysectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"id"];

    if
        ([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        
    }else{
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        [myArray addObject:stringId];

        NSLog(@"myArray %@",myArray);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: have u initialized myArray?

Comment: Yes i had initialized @hamentmiglani

Comment: WHERE are you getting nil? If you are having problems with initialising the array, then this is nothing to do with the tableview functions.  Have you confirmed that your array is correctly populated?

Comment: in ns log i am getting  my array is nill, yes my array is correctly populated @Russell

Comment: It cannot be nil and correctly populated!

Comment: Where you are initialising your array can you post that code here ?

Comment: in the .h i am assigning like this                                                        @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray  *myArray;
 and also synthesized in .m

Comment: did u initialize myArray like that

myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: its workng fine thanks @hamentmiglani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First create an outlet for an array and synthesise in the .m
2. Now initialise the array in the viewdidLoad
3. Now implement the cellforrowatIndexpath and didSelectRowAtIndexPath

   Find the code and let me know if u have want clarification

```html
String_Name = [ArrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if
        ([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        
    }else{
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        [myArray addObject:String_Name];

        NSLog(@"myArray %@",myArray);
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

Before you should create new `NSMubaleArray *storeArray;` NSMutableArray with allocation `storeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` in `viewDidLoad`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            if ([storeArray containsObject:[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
            {
                [storeArray removeObject:[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            }else{
            [storeArray addObject: [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if ([storeArray containsObject:[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
            {
                [storeArray removeObject:[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            }else{
                [storeArray addObject: [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            }
            break;
        case 3 :
            if ([storeArray containsObject:[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
            {
                [storeArray removeObject:[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            }else{
                [storeArray addObject: [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",storeArray);
}
```